# Converting List of List or RDD to DataFrame in Spark-Scala

Tags: scala, exception, casting, apache-spark-sql, rdd

So basically what I am trying to achieve is - I have a table with 4 columns (say) and I expose it to a DataFrame - DF1. Now I want to store each of the row of the DF1 to another hive table (basically DF2 which schema as - Column1, Column2, Column3) while the column3 value will be the '-' delimited row of DataFrame DF1.

```
val df = hiveContext.sql("from hive_table SELECT *")
val writeToHiveDf = df.filter(new Column("id").isNotNull)

var builder : List[(String, String, String)] = Nil
    var finalOne  =  new ListBuffer[List[(String, String, String)]]()
    writeToHiveDf.rdd.collect().foreach {
      row =>
        val item = row.mkString("-@")
        builder = List(List("dummy", "NEVER_NULL_CONSTRAINT", "some alpha")).map{case List(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)}
        finalOne += builder
    }
```

Now I have the **finalOne** as a list of lists, which I want to convert to a dataframe directly or via RDD.

```
var listRDD = sc.parallelize(finalOne) //Converts to RDD - It works. 
val dataFrameForHive : DataFrame = listRDD.toDF("table_name", "constraint_applied", "data") //Doesn't work
```

**Error :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:94)
```

Can some one help me understand the right way to convert this to DataFrame. Thanks a ton in advance for your support.

Comment: what schema do you expect the dataframe to have, 3 columns of type string or 1 column of type array whose elements are structs (3 Strings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe flattening your 'finalOne' dataframe before passing it onto the sc.parallelize() function should give an outcome in lines with what you are expecting.

`var listRDD = sc.parallelize(finalOne)`

`val dataFrameForHive : DataFrame = listRDD.toDF("table_name", "constraint_applied", "data")`

Comment: I believe addition of it in the community wiki would be of super-help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want 3 columns of type string in your dataframe, you should flatten your `List[List[(String,String,String)]]` to `List[(String,String,String)]`:

```
var listRDD = sc.parallelize(finalOne.flatten) // makes List[(String,String,String)]
val dataFrameForHive : DataFrame = listRDD.toDF("table_name", "constraint_applied", "data")
```